# Renaming all files ending with a specific pattern

Tags: file-io, vb6

I have many files within a directory and their names end with a variable pattern. I would like rename them to something shorter. The file names are of this format:

```
************_A.tif
************_B.tif
************_C.tif
```

And would like to name them to something like:

```
A.tif
B.tif
C.tif
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What if you have 2 files in the folder that end with the same pattern? Like `abc123_A.tif` and `123abc_A.tif`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Dir and Name functions

for example:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strNew As String
  Dim strType As String
  Dim lngLen As Long
  'set path
  strPath = "c:\temp\test"
  'set file type
  strType = ".tif"
  'set pattern length
  lngLen = Len(strType) + 1
  'find first file
  strFile = Dir$(strPath & "\*" & strType)
  'loop through all files of the selected type
  Do Until Len(strFile) = 0
    'show current filename
    Print "File : " & strFile
    'create new filename
    strNew = Right$(strFile, lngLen)
    'show new filename
    Print "New name : " & strNew
    'rename file to new filename
    Name strPath & "\" & strFile As strPath & "\" & strNew
    'find next file
    strFile = Dir$()
  Loop
End Sub
```

You might have to change the line which creates the new filename though as there might be files which get the same new name